# Cannot use a bitwise And with a negative number

Tags: vb.net, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

It appears that any bitwise operator with a negative number won't happen.  Even something as simple

```
    Dim b As SByte = CSByte(-128 And &HFF)
```

But the computer returns "Constant expression not representable in type 'SByte'"  Why would that not work?  Just to be safe, I tried to surround it with a conversion.  `SByte` as `-128` is `1000 0000` and `&HFF` is `1111 1111`.  Line them up and

```
 1000 0000
 1111 1111 And
 1000 0000
```

Which is still `-128` and legal for `SByte`.  What am I missing?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: When you say "won't happen", what actually happens? *Something* has to happen, other than what you expected.

Comment: Greg, it won't compile.  That was a bit vague on my part.  Sorry.

Comment: But the actual result of `-128 And &HFF` is 128, right? As an Integer?

Comment: Harold, if it were allowed, I think it would come up -128 as SByte and 128 as everything else.

Comment: If it won't compile, why have you not provided the compiler error instead of making us guess what the problem might be?

Comment: "Constant expression not representable in type 'SByte'.  I understand that SByte cannot represent 128 because it has a limit as of 127.  But, I don't understand why when doing bitwise operations the type matters.  I would expect that

Comment: It's because VB has overflow checking on by default.  If you turn that off, the compiler error won't happen.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

By default, VB has integer overflow checking enabled.  The compiler can see that the result of (-128 and &HFF) would overflow the signed byte so it gives the compiler error:  `Constant expression not representable in type 'SByte'`.

The code below will compile, but will generate a System.OverflowException at runtime since the result (128) is outside the range for a signed byte (with overflow checking turned on):

```
Public Shared Sub Main()
    Dim i As Integer = -128 And &HFF
    Dim b As SByte = CSByte(i)
    Console.WriteLine(b)
End Sub
```

If you go into your project's properties, and look under Advanced Compile Options, you will see an option to "**Remove integer overflow checks**".  If you check this value the code will compile and the result in b will be -128.  Removing integer overflow checks can result in unexpected values in overflow conditions, so you will have to watch out for those.

You can also use a Byte variable and the result in b will be 128:

```
Public Shared Sub Main()
    Dim b As Byte = CByte(-128 And &HFF)
    Console.WriteLine(b)
End Sub
```